# How to check diagonally

Tags: python

I have a 2-d list and I want to check it diagonally, but its only checking one of the diagonal lines and ignoring the rest

its a 6x6 grid:

```
if sum(self.TTT[i][i] for i in (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)) in (-3,3):
        for i in range(-3,3):            
            self.label['text']=('0 You WIN!')
            self.end() 
if sum(self.TTT[i][i] for i in (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)) in (-105,105):
        for i in range(-105,105):            
            self.label['text']=('- You WIN!')
            self.end()
if sum(self.TTT[i][i] for i in (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)) in (-300,300):
        for i in range(-300,300):            
            self.label['text']=('X You WIN!')
            self.end()
```

Why is it not going through all the diagonals ?

Comment: Is it the indentation? the 2nd two `ifs` are only executed if the first is `true`

Comment: Sorry I actually have the indentation correct on my file but here it appeared like that

Comment: What other diagonals do you want? Maybe you want to use `self.TTT[i][i+1]`, `self.TTT[i][i+2]` etc... ?

Comment: I tried that it doesn't work says out of range. I want check all the others across and down

Answer (score 0):

This part of your code,

```
self.TTT[i][i] for i in (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

produces each of these in order:

```
self.TTT[0][0]
self.TTT[1][1]
self.TTT[2][2]
self.TTT[3][3]
self.TTT[4][4]
self.TTT[5][5]
```

and no other coordinates. No wonder only one diagonal is checked!

What you need, then, is to have a *nested* pair of for loops, at least. Perhaps something like this:

```
for x in range(-6,7):
    total = 0

    for y in range(7):
        if 0 <= x+y <= 6:
            total += self.TTT[y][x+y]

    if abs(total) == 3:
        self.label['text']=('0 You WIN!')
        self.end()
    elif abs(total) == 105:
        self.label['text']=('0 You WIN!')
        self.end()
    elif abs(total) == 300:
        self.label['text']=('0 You WIN!')
        self.end()
```

Run this code to see why:

```
for x in range(-6,7):
    for y in range(7):
        if 0 <= x+y <= 6:
            print(x+y,y)
    print()
```

If you want to check the *anti*-diagonals as well, then I'll let you figure that out. It's a good exercise. :)